# Keep java site files after deploy/undeploy

Tags: java, tomcat

I learn how to develop Java web applications.  I made a site where I can upload images and  PDF-s.  First, I deploy the war file on the tomcat server.  I uploaded some image and PDF files , and , after I change something in the site code, after redeploying, my files that were uploaded are deleted from the server. Is there  a solution to keep files on the server  when the site is deployed/undeployed ?  In the case when there will be 2-3 Gb of files which is the solution to keep the files. Thanks!

Comment: create a different domain for your static data

Answer (score 2):

Save them out of webapp context.

Let me explain: your webapp goes in ROOT or in a self defined context (ie. /yourapp) inside the tomcat/webapps/, just store them in a folder like tomcat/app-data, those will be kept safe.

This is i.e. the Liferay approach (it's a well known J2EE portal). Just choose a safe location on your storage.

Pay attention to file permissions and to selinux context, if you have SELinux enabled.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Simply do not store in your tomcat app directory. Create a separate folder in your filesystem for storing files.

Comment: which will be the url of the file after storing it outside the tomcat app directory ?

Comment: you can use absolute positioning i.e. /opt/yourapp/files/ ,/var/lib/yourapp/files   or positioning withing the tomcat installation dir something like System.getProperty("catalina.base")+"/yourapp/files/" . Then you can keep the path  where you store your files in a configuration properties file of your app or as a context parameter in web.xml (if it makes sense for you system).